# Windows debugger won't catch breakpoint

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm running a process with the debugger attached. But when a breakpoint is triggered, the debugger doesn't actually break. The output window clearly shows that the process has triggered a breakpoint, it's written right there.

```
The thread 0x10c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
blah.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
The program '[5672] blah.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

But it didn't actually *break*, it just carries on as if the breakpoint wasn't executed. In fact, I set breakpoints in the body of `f()` and they are hit like normal. `f()` actually succeeds (it's a test function)- as if there was no breakpoint and no problem. Everything works fine, except for the mysterious breakpoint that the debugger won't break on.

How can I convince the debugger to really break on the breakpoint? I want to know if my tests really succeed or not.

Comment: Why add `windbg` tag... the sample output is from Visual Studio.

Comment: Is the function called from multiple threads ?

Comment: No, it is definitely not.

Comment: What is the offending line?

Comment: have you tried to use a different debugger like ollydbg? you can set a static volatile string in the function called and located it in the assembly and check if ollydbg can stop at the breakpoint

Comment: It`s time to debug debugger.